# Remove single quote from input

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to remove a single quote, but I don't know how to do it.
I leave the related code here.

```
response.write "Original: " & rs2("comentario") 
comentario = Replace(rs2("comentario"), "Ã±", "ñ") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, "Ã³", "ó") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, "fÆ", "ó") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, "Â³", "ó") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, "Ã", "") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, "Â", "") 
comentario = Replace(comentario, Chr(39), "")
comentario = Replace(comentario, "'", "")
comentario = Replace(comentario, "\'", "")
response.write "<br>Modificado: " & comentario & "<br>-----------------------<br>"
```

The result from the code above is this

```
Original: reuniÃ³n INNOVAE IÃ'igo IÃ±ake
Modificado: reunión INNOVAE I'igo Iñake
-----------------------
```

Comment: You appear to have a character encoding problem.  Take a look at this article https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this changing the encoding part of the page from

```
<%
CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"
Response.CodePage = 28591
%>
```

To

```
<%
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
%>
```

and saving it as UTF-8 on Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or what problem you're encountering. If you want to remove all apostrophes (U+0027) from a string, then what you're doing of

```
comentario = Replace(comentario, "'", "")
```

should work just fine. (And using `chr(39)` instead of `"'"` would be equivalent.

It may be that the character you're trying to replace isn't actually an apostrophe, though, but some other similar-looking character. And perhaps you're outputting in a character set that doesn't support the actual character in the string, and it's being replaced with the closest best-match in the output (which is a U+0027 apostrophe) that you end up seeing. Those are just guesses, though, and it's hard to know for sure without knowing more about your setup and what you're actually trying to do.

In the bigger picture, it looks like you're trying to somehow fix up prior data that got transferred with the wrong character encoding. Unless you're trying to fix data that was irreversibly corrupted in this way in the past, you're probably better off correcting that issue and ensure that your data is transferred with the correct encoding at all points in your workflow. Make sure that `Response.CharSet` and `Response.CodePage` is set the way you're expecting for whatever text encoding you're trying to use, and that you're properly handling form inputs in the encoding set by the browser.

Comment: I'm trying to print a bad saved string on the database. At the db, this string is saved as reuniÃ³n INNOVAE IÃ´igo IÃ±ake, and I don't know how to remove that apostrophe.

Comment: There's no apostrophe in your comment; you have a U+00B4 Acute Accent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I created for fixing funny characters:

I USE FN_CLEAN TO "CLEAN" STUFF FOR DATABASE INSERT/UPDATE:

```
function fn_clean(FixWhat)
    if (isempty(FixWhat) or isnull(FixWhat) or FixWhat="") then
        FixWhat=""
    else
        apos=chr(39)
        quot=chr(34)

        FixWhat=trim(FixWhat)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"''",apos & apos,1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"'''",apos,1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBNullChar,"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBNullString,"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBTab," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBVerticalTab," ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<ahref=","<a href=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<ahref =","<a href=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<imgsrc","<img src",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<spanclass=","<span class=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<spanclass =","<span class=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//<![CDATA[","",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//]]","",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&lt;","<",1,-1,1)      
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&gt;",">",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"/","&#47;",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"../../../images/","/images/",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"’",apos,1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"’",apos,1,-1,1)        
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"`",apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(145),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(146),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(180),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(184),apos,1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"_new","_BLANK",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"_NEW","_BLANK",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"ñ","&#241;",1,-1,1)

        'quotes     
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(132),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(147),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(148),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(152),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(168),quot,1,-1,1)

        'hyphens
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(150),"-",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(151),"--",1,-1,1)

        'dot dot dot
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(133),"...",1,-1,1)

        'line feed
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(10),"[chr-10 was here]",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(12),"[chr-12 was here]",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(13),"[chr-13 was here]",1,-1,1)

        'CR
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(21),"<br>",1,-1,1)

        'now for everything higher than char 128
        'for i = 129 to 255
        '   c = "&#" & i & ";"
        '   FixWhat = replace(FixWhat,Chr(i),"&#39;",1,-1,1)
        'next

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,quot,quot & quot)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br>" & vbCrLf & "<br>" & vbCrLf & "<br>" & vbCrLf,"<br>" & vbCrLf & "<br>" & vbCrLf,1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,vbCrLf & vbCrLf,vbCrLf,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><br><br><br>","<br><br>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><br><br>","<br><br>",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<table><br>","<table>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</td><br>","</td>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<tr><br>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><tr>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</tr><br>","</tr>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br></tr>","</tr>",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><embed","<embed",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"background=" & quot & " ","background=" & quot & quot & " ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt =","title=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt=","title=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt=  ","alt= ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt= ","title=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=" & chr(34) & chr(34),"title=image",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"title=image ",1,-1,1)


        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"align=" & quot & " ","align=left ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"border=" & quot & " "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"this=" & quot & " "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"width=" & quot & " ","width=10 ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"x=" & quot & " "," ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"[quote]","&#34;",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,quot,"&#34;",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"'","&#39;",1,-1,1)
    end if
    fn_clean=FixWhat
End Function
```

AND THIS ONE I USE TO "DIRTY IT UP FOR SCREEN/INPUT BOXES, ETC:

```
Function fn_dirty(FixWhat)
    if (isnull(FixWhat) or FixWhat="") then
        FixWhat=""
    else
        FixWhat=trim(FixWhat)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<ahref","<a href",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<spanclass","<span class",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#241;","ñ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&apos;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%27","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#39;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#47;","/",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"''''","'''",1,-1,1)


        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#34;",chr(34),1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%22",chr(34),1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(13) & chr(10),"",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#10;" & "&#10;","",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,vbCrLf & vbCrLf,vbCrLf,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(34)&chr(34)&chr(34),chr(34),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(10),"[chr10 was here]",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(12),"[chr12 was here]",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(13),"[chr13 was here]",1,-1,1)


        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(34) & chr(34),chr(34),1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt='" & chr(32) & "'","alt=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt=" & chr(34) & chr(32) & chr(34),"title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt='" & chr(32),"alt=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt='" & chr(32),"alt=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"alt=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"alt=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=","alt=",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title='" & chr(32) & "'","title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=" & chr(34) & chr(32) & chr(34),"title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title='" & chr(32),"title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title='" & chr(32),"title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"title=Put-image-title-here-instead-of-OceanMedia.net" & chr(32),1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"src=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"src=" & chr(34) & "/images","src=" & chr(34) & "images",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"background=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"background=" & chr(34) & chr(34) & chr(32),1,-1,1)



        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"x=" & chr(34) & chr(32)," ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&lt;","<",1,-1,1)      
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&gt;",">",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//<![CDATA[","",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//]]","",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TABLE","<table",1,-1,1)       
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TBODY>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TR","<tr",1,-1,1)             
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TD","<td",1,-1,1) 
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</TR>","</tr>",1,-1,1)             
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</TD>","</td>",1,-1,1) 

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<html><br>","<html>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<head><br>","<head>",1,-1,1)       
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<body><br>","<body>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><tbody>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<tbody><br>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><tr>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<tr><br>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><td","<td",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br></html>","</html>",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"#34;#34;#34;","&#34;&#34;",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"#39;#39;#39;","&#39;&#39;",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#34;&#34;&#34;","&#34;&#34;",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#39;&#39;&#39;","&#39;&#39;",1,-1,1)

    end if
    fn_dirty=FixWhat
End Function
```